# Lucene document Boosting

Tags: java, lucene, scoring

I am having problem with lucene boosting, Iam trying to boost a particular document which matches with the (firstname)field specified
I have posted the part of the code

```
private static Document createDoc(String lucDescription,String primaryk,String specialString){
  Document doc = new Document();
  doc.add(new Field("lucDescription",lucDescription, Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.TOKENIZED));
  doc.add(new Field("primarykey",primaryk,Field.Store.YES,Field.Index.NO));
  doc.add(new Field("specialDescription",specialString, Field.Store.NO, Field.Index.UN_TOKENIZED));
  doc.setBoost ((float)(0.00001));
  if (specialString.equals("chris"))
  doc.setBoost ((float)(100000.1));
  return doc;
}
```

why is this not working?

```
public static String dbSearch(String searchString){
  List<String> pkList = new ArrayList<String>();
  String conCat="(";
  try{
   String querystr = searchString;

   Query query = new QueryParser("lucDescription", new StandardAnalyzer()).parse(querystr);  
   IndexSearcher searchIndex = new IndexSearcher("/home/athreya/docsIndexFile");
   // Index of the User table--> /home/araghu/aditya/indexFile.
   Hits hits = searchIndex.search(query);
   System.out.println("Found " + hits.length() + " hits.");
   for(int iterator=0;iterator<hits.length();iterator++) {
    String primKey=hits.doc(iterator).get("primarykey");
    System.out.println(primKey);
    pkList.add(primKey);
   }
   searchIndex.close();
```

Thank you in advance
Athreya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to say what could be wrong just looking at the code, couple of things to try:

1. open the index with Luke and see the score for the document (containing "chris")
2. Unsure if you are bypassing one or the other setboost calls.

   if (specialString.equals("chris"))
        doc.setBoost ((float)(100000.1));
   else
       doc.setBoost ((float)(0.00001));

Comment: if (specialString.equals("chris")) doc.setBoost ((float)(100000.1)); else doc.setBoost ((float)(0.00001));here
I am trying here to nullify the boost if the doc is not found and maximise it if found so that the score for the doc if found will be high

Comment: ok, but your code above seems counterintuitive, perhaps put the un-boost in an else statement. Also look at the index using Luke, that would tell you a lot more about scoring.